# display different prefix according gender in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```php
$all_categories = get_cats($cat);
echo "&nbsp&nbsp"."Sons";

for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++) {     
    $arr = get_gender($cat);

    if ($arr[$i]=='0') {
        echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i].",";
    }  
} 

echo "&nbsp&nbsp"."Daughters";

for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++) {     
    $arr = get_gender($cat);

    if ($arr[$i]=='1') {
        echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i].",";
    }
}
```

In `$all_categories` I'm getting all child of a given id and `get_cats` and `get_gender` are functions.

`0` is for male and `1` is for female. I want to display the word "Sons" first then their names and then count of sons and then word "Daughters" and their names and count of daughters.

Now I am displaying the word "sons" then their names and then the word "daughters" and their names but the words "sons" and "daughters" are being displayed even if given id has no children.

Comment: How about formatting the code to make it readable? How about transgender people or people without gender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested code with more untested code added :-) 
As you do not know if you have any 'sons' until you are in the 'for' loop, and there may be none. You have to print the heading the 'first time' you print any 'sons'. Alas, that means a 'first_time' flag with your current code.

Edited to display child counts. Then i hope the answer will be accepted.

Added printing all the names on one line followed by the count.

Added storing counts separately and show simple 'and' test on the counts.

```
$all_categories = get_cats($cat);

$headingPrinted = false;
$sonCount = 0;
$outputLine = '';

for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++) {     
    $arr = get_gender($cat);

    if ($arr[$i]=='0') {

        if (!$headingPrinted) {
          $outputLine .= "&nbsp&nbsp"."Sons";
          $headingPrinted = true;
        }    

        // append to the current outputLine...  
        $outputLine .= "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i].",";
        $sonCount++;
    }  
} 
// print $outputline and child count if at least one was found. show plural if more than one 
if ($sonCount >= 1) {
   echo $outputLine, $childCount, $childCount == 1 ? 'son': 'sons', ' found';  
} 
else {
  // you may want to do something if none found
}


// repeat for the other heading

$headingPrinted = false;
$daughterCount = 0;
$outputLine = '';

for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++) {     
    $arr = get_gender($cat);

    if ($arr[$i]=='1') {

      if (!$headingPrinted) {
        $outputLine .= "&nbsp&nbsp"."Daughters";
        $headingPrinted = true;
      }    


      // append to the current outputLine...  
      $outputLine .= "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i].",";
      $daughterCount++;
    }
}  

// print child count if at least one was found 
if ($daughterCount >= 1) {
   echo $outputLine, $childCount, $childCount == 1 ? 'daughter': 'daughters', ' found';  
} 
else {
  // you may want to do something if none found
}

// test combined totals of children...
if ($sonCount == 1 &&  daughterCount == 1) {
   echo 'wow - one of each';   
}
```

Comment: thanks..It solved my problem but i want to display count of sons and count of daughters after their names. What about that?

Comment: I want to display like this Sons:a,b,c,d:4; Daughters:p,q,r,s:4; Can you tell me about that???

Comment: Updated the answer to print the names on one line. :-)

Comment: I want to Display count only if son count is greater than 2 and same for daughters. I want exactly the same result like                     this first condition if son and daughter count less than 2     Sons:a,b; Daughters:p,q;second condition if son and daughter count greater than 2   Sons:a,b,c:3;    Daughters:p,q,r:3;

Comment: You should be able to change the existing tests very easily for the "> 2" instead of the ">= 1". Try changing the code yourself. If you wnt to start combining the results of sons and daughter counts then just store them in separate variables and test at the end. I will demonstrate with the 'answer'.

Comment: i did that early but if count is greater than 2 then its ok but when less than 3 it display both comma and semicolon at the end of names..